# Why does my m4a audio play with html5, but not with fetch and blob uri on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, audio

I'm having a hard time with this. I can't get my audio to play in Chrome on Android 8. If I use the `audio` element, my m4a audio will play fine. What I want to do is fetch the audio, and use a blob uri instead.

The code works on desktop, and iOS Safari. But when I try it on Chrome Android, I get the `DEMUXER_ERROR_DETECTED_AAC` error.

Unfortunately, you can't just run the SO snippet on your mobile device, so I've provided the fiddle here too. If you navigate to the fiddle on Chrome Android, the HTML audio will play fine, but the `fetch` audio won't.

https://jsfiddle.net/mtycholaz/v1r7xhck/16/show

```
const audio = new Audio();
let blobUri = '';

audio.addEventListener('error', (ev) => {
  console.log('error', ev.srcElement.error.message);
  document.getElementById('duration').innerText = ev.srcElement.error.message;
});

audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  document.getElementById('duration').innerText = 'Length: ' + audio.duration;
});

fetch('https://leaderfoldera5b0.blob.core.windows.net/client/Symphony%20No.6%20(1st%20movement).m4a?sv=2019-02-02&st=2020-05-24T01%3A21%3A54Z&se=2021-05-25T01%3A21%3A00Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=NHESmCHWR23EltpmSRnmibh8cwSH%2Fn%2FU1NmI2VOzTvI%3D', {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }

}).then((response) => {
  response.blob().then(result => {
    blobUri = URL.createObjectURL(result);
    document.getElementById('play').innerText = 'Play'
  });
});

document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.src = blobUri;
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
});
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
<button id="play">
  Downloading audio...
</button>
<br/>
<span id="duration"></span>
<br/>
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://leaderfoldera5b0.blob.core.windows.net/client/Symphony%20No.6%20(1st%20movement).m4a?sv=2019-02-02&st=2020-05-24T01%3A21%3A54Z&se=2021-05-25T01%3A21%3A00Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=NHESmCHWR23EltpmSRnmibh8cwSH%2Fn%2FU1NmI2VOzTvI%3D" type="audio/x-m4a" />
</audio>
```